# how to create a score in facebook application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

from facebook docs it says:
"You can post a score or a user by issuing an HTTP POST request to /USER_ID/scores with the app access_token as long as you have the publish_actions permission."

well i have publish_actions permission and i'm trying the following code but it doesn't work...

```
require('php-sdk/src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => '123546321654654654654',
'secret' => 'd9132156afasdfadsfsdfewfg79f5f16d0', 
'cookie' => true
));
$attachment = array('score' => 1005);
$postscore = $facebook->api('/12345612/score/','POST',$attachment);
```

Comment: How doesn't it work. Does it return something or provide an error or just return nothing?

Comment: it is not returning any thing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your app access token in the attachment array. So simply update your array attachment to

```
$attachment = array( 'score' => 1005, 'access_token' => $facebook->getAppId().'|'.$facebook->getApiSecret() )
$postscore = $facebook->api('/12345612/score/','POST',$attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with php but link for posting the score is "/USER_ID/scores/". You have forgotten one 's' in the end of the scores.

Comment: tried scores but still the same problem , nothing returned and the page stops loading...

Comment: Are the app registered as a game? try to remove "/" after scores

Comment: try catch gives me this:  (#15) This method must be called with an app access_token. so how to get the access token and use it for a code like mine.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ there  is an example how to get app access token